# issues with media plugin generator behavior

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to cakePHP and MVC as well so maybe I got some major design flaws in my attempt. Excuse my spelling as well since im not a native speaker.

#### What I'm trying to do:

I want to create a view where the user can re-crop uploaded images using the Jcrop Javascript lib and the [Media Plugin from David Persson](https://github.com/bmcclure/CakePHP-Media-Plugin).

#### Setup:

All mediafiles are stored by the Attachment Model which is based of the one shipped with the Mediaplugin.
Other Models can use the Attachment Model to store mediafiles.

#### My Attempt:

1. (*View/Attachments/admin_edit.ctp*): Gather cropdata, data will injected to the form via javascript
2. (*Controller/AttachmentsController.php*)

   - Save attachment data
   - if attachment data was saved: process cropdata with use of `$this->Attachment->makeVersion($file, $instructions);`
   - redirect to attachments indexview using `$this->redirect(array($admin = true, 'controller' =>
     'attachments', 'action' => 'index'));`

#### Issue:

My general attempt is working, so all images get croped like i want them to but the following redirect isn't fired, instead a weird redirect to current action is executed somewhere.
I narrowed it down to the makeVersion() method, when i comment that out, the attachment gets still saved and the redirect is working like it's supposed to.

So it seems that makeVersion() has some weird sideeffect.

Since i get redirected it is really hard to debug because i cannot inspect the request or check for errors.
I tried with using debug();exit; to narrow it further down inside of the makeVersion() method but i really don't get this, theres no redirects called anywhere inside.

#### Code:

For anyone still reading and interested in helping me, check out the source [here](https://github.com/KingLoui/mediatest/blob/master/app/Controller/AttachmentsController.php)

Thanks in advance for your effort!
Cheers
Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a little embarassing, but all the time CodeKit, my local less compiler, reloaded the tab as soon as the thumbnail was saved. *facepalm*